# Yum error on Centos 6.4

Tags: centos, x86-64, yum

Yum suddenly start to give the error pasted bellow

I tried to rebuild yum, but the error remains. I re-installed krb5-libs, but the error remains

How can I repair yum without reinstating Centos?

Error:

> There was a problem importing one of the Python modules
>   required to run yum. The error leading to this problem was:
>
> /lib64/libkrb5.so.3: symbol krb5int_push_fscreatecon_for, version krb5support_0_MIT not defined in file libkrb5support.so.0 with link time reference
>
> Please install a package which provides this module, or
>   verify that the module is installed correctly.
>
> It's possible that the above module doesn't match the
>   current version of Python, which is:
>   2.6.6 (r266:84292, Jul 10 2013, 22:48:45) 
>   [GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3)]
>
> If you cannot solve this problem yourself, please go to 
>   the yum faq at:
>    http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/Faq

Answer (score 2):

At my machine the issue was caused by a second libkrb5support.so distributed with PostgreSQL 5.2 / PSqlODBC. After commenting the library path in /etc/ld.so.conf.d/psqlODBC.conf and runing ldconfig -v, I can run yum again without any issue.

In my case, the path to the "wrong" library is /opt/PostgreSQL/9.2/lib/libkrb5support.so.0

Edgar.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this error after defining `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable. It was fixed by adding /lib and /lib64 to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib:/lib64:....
```

Answer (score 0):

Run the below command to test what all the libraries you have:

```
# ldd /lib64/libkrb5.so.3
```

And make sure that the module 'libkrb5support.so.0' is available under '/lib64' directory or having the soft ink to the files that is inside /lib64 directory. If its not there then this error is expected. So manually you have to link it again.

From my test system:

```
# locate libkrb5support.so.0
/lib64/libkrb5support.so.0

# ls -l /lib64/libkrb5support.so.0
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 21 Aug 19 15:52 /lib64/libkrb5support.so.0 -> libkrb5support.so.0.1

# ls -l /lib64/libkrb5support.so.0.1 
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 46336 May  1  2012 /lib64/libkrb5support.so.0.1
```